# Arithmetic calculation using infix notation

Tags: scheme, racket

Following function works to calculate infix notation with parentheses:

```
(define (mycalc ll)
  (cond
    [(= 1 (length ll))
     (first ll)]

    [(empty? (flatten(rest ll)))
     (first ll)]

    [(= 2 (length ll))
     (printf "Error: only 2 elements: ~a" ll)
     (exit)]

    [(list? (first ll))
     (mycalc (append (list (mycalc (first ll)) (second ll) (third ll)) (rest(rest(rest ll)))))]

    [(list? (third ll))
     (mycalc (append (list (first ll) (second ll) (mycalc (third ll)) (rest(rest(rest ll))))))]

    [(= 3 (length ll))
     ((second ll) (first ll) (third ll))]

    [else
     (mycalc (append (list ((second ll) (first ll) (third ll))) (rest(rest(rest ll)))))]))
```

Testing:

```
(define L (list (list 3 * 6) + 5 + (list 2 - (list 2 * (list 21 / 3)))))
(mycalc L)
```

Output:

11

However, it does not work with following version of list:

```
(define L '((3 * 6) + 5 + (2 - (2 * (21 / 3)))))
(mycalc L)
```

Following is the error:

```
application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: '*
  arguments...:
```

How can `'*` be identified as a function to correct this error?

### Edit:

I used `'match'` for '* etc and now this short function works well:

```
(define (mycalc ll)
  (define (solve a b c)
    (match b
      ['+ (+ a c)]
      ['- (- a c)]
      ['* (* a c)]
      ['/ (/ a c)]))
  (cond
    [(= 1 (length ll))
     (first ll)]
    [(list? (first ll))
     (mycalc (cons (mycalc (first ll))
                   (rest ll)))]
    [(list? (third ll))
     (mycalc (append (list (first ll)
                           (second ll)
                           (mycalc (third ll)))
                     (rest(rest(rest ll)))))]
    [else
     (mycalc (cons (solve (first ll) (second ll) (third ll))
                   (rest(rest(rest ll)))))]))
```

Testing:

```
(define L '((3 * 6) + 5 + (2 - (2 * (21 / 3)))))
(mycalc L)
```

Output:

```
11
```

Please note that this function does not handle precedence, and it will solve strictly from left to right if no parentheses are used.

Comment: `'*` is not a function; it is a symbol, similar to a string in that it has no relation to the function `*` except that it's characters happen to match up with an identifier name bound to the `*` function.

Comment: If you want to use infix syntax there are several options. You could use [`#lang sweet-exp`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/sweet/index.html) and write `{{3 * 6} + 5}`, or you could use [`(require infix)`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/infix-manual/index.html) and write `@${(3 * 6) + 5}`, or you could use a macro to define infix syntax.

Comment: But no matter how you do infix syntax, I would recommend avoiding `quote`

Comment: You can combine these useful comments into an answer. Readers are also more likely to read answers rather than comments

Comment: Okay, I've made this into an answer, with more examples and some explanation of how `quote` ruins it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your attempts is that you are using `quote`, which as you know "distributes" itself over elements of a list, so that you end up with `'(2 * x)` transforming into `(list '2 '* 'x)`.

```
#lang racket
(define (f x)
  (my-calc '(2 * x))) ; this is completely broken because of quote
```

This has two problems, the `'*` and the `'x`. Here `'*` is not a function; it is a symbol, similar to a string in that it has no relation to the function `*` except that it's characters happen to match up with an identifier name bound to the `*` function. The same is true for `'x`, except that it's not even a known thing: you can't even look it up to find it!

The root of both: `quote` destroys lexical scope.

If you want infix syntax without running into these problems, there are several options, and all of them involve the syntax being transformed at compile-time. This way the lexical scope is preserved.

## 1: [`#lang sweet-exp`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/sweet/index.html)

The `sweet-exp` language modifies the reader so that whenever it sees `{ ... }`, it reads the expressions inside as infix. You have the option of writing `{{3 * 6} + 5}` instead of `(+ (* 3 6) 5)`, and it will be equivalent.

```
#lang sweet-exp racket

(define (f x)
  {2 * x})

(define (p x)
  {{3 * (sqr x)} + {6 * x} + 5})
```

## 2: [`(require infix)`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/infix-manual/index.html)

The `infix` library provides `$` as a macro such that `@${ ... }` will be interpreted as infix, so you have the option of writing `@${(3 * 6) + 5}` instead of `(+ (* 3 6) 5)`.

```
#lang at-exp racket
(require infix)

(define (f x)
  @${2 * x})

(define (p x)
  @${(3 * x^2) + (6 * x) + 5})
```

## 3: Defining your own macro

You can define a simple infix macro like this:

```
#lang racket
(require syntax/parse/define)

(define-syntax-parser infix
  #:literals [+ *]
  #:datum-literals [^]
  [(_ n:number) #'n]
  [(_ x:id) #'x]
  [(_ (a:expr + b:expr)) #'(+ (infix a) (infix b))]
  [(_ (a:expr * b:expr)) #'(* (infix a) (infix b))]
  [(_ (a:expr ^ b:expr)) #'(expt (infix a) (infix b))])
```

If you want `+` and `*` to be able to be chained together multiple times like `(x + y + z)`, you can extend the macro with `...+` for repetition one or more times and `~seq` for grouping patterns together.

```
(define-syntax-parser infix
  #:literals [+ *]
  #:datum-literals [^]
  [(_ n:number) #'n]
  [(_ x:id) #'x]
  [(_ (a:expr (~seq + b:expr) ...+)) #'(+ (infix a) (infix b) ...)]
  [(_ (a:expr (~seq * b:expr) ...+)) #'(* (infix a) (infix b) ...)]
  [(_ (a:expr ^ b:expr)) #'(expt (infix a) (infix b))])

(define (f x)
  (infix (2 * x)))

(define (p x)
  (infix ((3 * (x ^ 2)) + (6 * x) + 5)))
```

Comment: To add - and / also, do I just add statements "[(_ (a:expr (~seq - b:expr) ...)) #'(- (infix a) (infix b) ...)]" and "[(_ (a:expr (~seq / b:expr) ...)) #'(/ (infix a) (infix b) ...)]" or do I need to do something more?

Comment: Yes, supporting `-` and `/` are no different here from supporting `+` and `*`, so you can do the same thing. You'll just have to remember to add `-` and `/` to the literals list.

Comment: Thanks for that comment; you made me realize I had a mistake in my patterns. I should have used `...+` instead of `...`, because I only want it to match one or more repetitions. I have corrected the answer.

Comment: Following simple definition does not work: (define (p x) (infix ((3 * (x ^ 2)) * 6 * x + 5)))

Comment: That's because this simple macro doesn't handle precedence. You'll have to write `(infix (((3 * (x ^ 2)) * 6 * x) + 5))` to do that. If you want your macro to handle precedence you'll have to do the parsing yourself: one way I've done this has used a hierarchy of syntax classes.

Comment: Is there any problem with the final function in my question above? It does not handle precedence but will solve from left to right if no parentheses are given.

Comment: If that's what you want, then `(a + b * c)` would be equivalent to `((a + b) * c)`. That would be fairly easy to write as a macro, but make sure you document its behavior, because otherwise it will be very confusing to people who are used to precedence.

Comment: I have added a note regarding this in my question above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on the answer by @Alex Knauth: In the first case, which uses `list` to construct the list, the individual list elements are not quoted and thus are evaluated. `(display L)` should produce an output more or less like this (details vary from implementation to implementation):

```
((3 #<procedure * (#:optional _ _ . _)> 6) #<procedure + (#:optional _ _ . _)>
  5 #<procedure + (#:optional _ _ . _)> (2 #<procedure - (#:optional _ _ . _)> 
 (2 #<procedure * (#:optional _ _ . _)> (21 #<procedure / (#:optional _ _ . _)> 3))))
```

As you can clearly see, the list contains various procedures. In the second case, which quotes the entire list, however, the individual list elements are not evaluated. As a result, the list contains no procedures, only symbols, and `(display L)` produces this:

```
((3 * 6) + 5 + (2 - (2 * (21 / 3))))
```

Comment: Can quote symbol be used in current fn?

Comment: @rnso I'm sorry, I do not understand the question.

Comment: Can '(4 + 3) be evaluated by a lang racket function?

Comment: @rnso No, and I am still not sure what you are trying to get at. Maybe you mean something like `(display (quasiquote (3 ,* 4)))`. There is a shorter way to write that, but it involves the symbol this site uses to introduce code, so I can't just type that.

Comment: Can '+ be converted to function + ?

Comment: @rnso You can convert a symbol to the value bound to that symbol by evaluating it. Either explicitly by saying `(eval '* (interaction-environment))` or by using `quasiquote` and unquoting the symbol within the quasiquoted expression.

Comment: I would recommend *against* using `eval`, and also against using `quote`. It destroys lexical scope and prevents you from using actual bindings.

Comment: @AlexKnauth Would you care to expand upon your comment regarding `quote`?

Comment: If you didn't have just `'(3 * 4)` but also `'(3 * x)` and similar things, they wouldn't work. You could add an explicit run-time environment to to `my-calc`, but that would have other problems. If you had multiple `x`s that shadowed one another, you would have to make sure that only the immediate one was added to the run-time environment. If one of the `x`s was a local variable in a macro, then you would need to keep both around with something to distinguish them. But when when you find `'x` in the expression, which binding is it referring to? That information is lost.

Comment: Or you could just add commas everywhere `(quasiquote ((1/2 ,* ,a (,t ,expt 2)) ,+ (,init-v ,* ,t) ,+ ,init-position))`. But that would start to look ugly pretty quick.

Comment: @AlexKnauth Thanks for the clarification.